# A single plist or more than one plist to store my responses

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, plist

I have this requirement to save my responses from web service API's to a plist.I have about 10 web service API's and that many responses. On the perspective of performance should i save the data to 10 different plists or just a plist with different keys?
Note: Data is not huge and stored only for a fixed period after which it would be deleted.

Comment: You can use core data for saving your responses data. Plist isn't better way.

Comment: @Tirth "Data is not huge and stored only for a fixed period after which it would be deleted." so IMO Core Data is a terrible idea.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis if data is small enough then why you not save it in serialized golbal class? I don't think so it will matter of performance of application.

Comment: @Tirth If thinks the performance is irrelevant too; see my answer. What do you mean by "serialized global class"?

Comment: @Tirth I am very much sceptical about core data in my case.I prefer plist to core data here. Could you please comment on serialized golbal class?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the plist's and write/read operations you are going to performs with the file. In either cases I would prefer to save each plist separately for performance, security and availability perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You worry about performance? So implement the two options, measure, and keep the best one based on the results.

However, in general the best course of action is:

1. Implement the simplest / more elegant solution;
2. When you think you have a performance problem, measure it, and if you get significant data to backup your suspicions, fix it (eventually by asking here how you could optimize your code);
3. After the fix, measure again. The performance issue is fixed: yay. The performance issue is still there: goto 2).

[Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize), yada yada..

Comment: Well considering your point,is there a right way to measure the performance?

Comment: [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) with time profiler. Observe how much time you spend in your saving/loading function(s).